# 301 редирект с суфиксом в .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Старый URL товара:

```
web-site/dorozki/begovaja-dorozka-detali
```

Новый URL товара:

```
web-site/dorozki/begovaja-dorozka
```

Как прописать редирект, чтобы сохранить старые ссылки?

Comment: "-detali" добавляется ко всем ссылкам товаров

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например, так:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(.+)-detali$ $1 [L,R=301]
```